# Angular highlight/select all content inside <div> element Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do we highlight and select all content inside a  element on click using Angular JS ?.
It is easy to do using inputbox. But how do we do for  element.

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you

This is what I have used so far.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="appController" ng-app="app">
    <input type="text" ng-model="content" ng-click="onTextClick($event)" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('appController',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.content = 'test';
        $scope.onTextClick = function ($event) {
            $event.target.select();
        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/onury/R63u5/

Comment: To get help, you will need to provide more information and show you already have tried something. Please provide a plunkr/jsfiddle we can work on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n63LhtcL/3/

Here is an updated directive to achieve it:

```
.directive('selectOnClick', function ($window) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                var selection = $window.getSelection();        
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(element[0]);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Your markup:

```
<div select-on-click>
    Some text...
    <input type="text" ng-model="content"  />
</div>
```

Comment: So this should work in <div> container too ? if I apply this directive? Input is easy. I want it to able to click on div container and select all text.

Comment: by `all text` you mean the text of the input field or all text of the div?

Comment: I meant all text inside div container. Best example to give you would be bitly.  http://cl.ly/image/033s3d0Q3O2p like here text is surrounded by container and once you click on it, it selects all text + shows you tooltip.